# How to texture map point cloud from Kinect with image taken by another camera?

Tags: kinect

Kinect camera has a very low resolution RGB image. I want to use point cloud from the depth kinect but want to texture map it with another image taken from another camera.

Could anyone please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Kinect Calibration Toolbox, v2.0 http://sourceforge.net/projects/kinectcalib/files/v2.0/

2012-02-09 - v2.0 - Major update. Added new disparity distortion model and simultaneous calibration of external RGB camera.